# Some environment variables are not visible in Ansible

Tags: bash, ansible

I am trying to convert an existing shell script into an Ansible role. In this role, I am reading two environment variables but Ansible does not display these even though it is available in the host. Can anyone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Note: I cannot hardcode env.sh into my Ansible role as each region will have its own settings.

/etc/synopsys/bin/env.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

SITEID="us01-savvis"
MYGLOBAL="/remote/kickstart"

export SITEID MYGLOBAL
```

Ansible code:

```
---
  - name: Gather Facts
    setup:
      gather_subset:
        - '!all'
        - '!any'
        - facter
        - network
        - hardware
    async: 300
    poll: 20

  - name: Check if env.sh exists
    stat:
      path: /etc/synopsys/bin/env.sh
    register: stat_result

  - name: Source env.sh file if it exists
    shell: "source /etc/synopsys/bin/env.sh"
    when: stat_result.stat.exists == True

  - name: Printing all the environment​ variables in Ansible
    debug:
      # msg: "{{ ansible_env }}"
      msg: "{{ lookup('env','SITEID','MYGLOBAL','HOME','SHELL') }}"
```

Ansible output (Note that `SITEID` and `MYGLOBAL` are not visible):

```
TASK [common/run_pkg_checker/v1 : Printing all the environment​ variables in Ansible] *************************************************
ok: [ansible-poc-cos6] => {
    "msg": ",,/u/subburat,/usr/local/bin/tcsh"
}
```

Linux environment variables (`SITEID` and `MYGLOBAL` defined):

```
[root@ansible-poc-cos6 ~]# env |grep MYGLOBAL
MYGLOBAL=/remote/kickstart
[root@ansible-poc-cos6 ~]# env |grep SITEID
SITEID=us01-savvis
```

Comment: your workflow isn't clear (to me). Do you know about sourcing env files inside of shell scripts? Either `. myEnvFile` or `source myEnvFile` will work. There is almost certainly something similar for ansible. (no experience there). Just try it. Good luck.

Comment: I am sourcing it already in the Ansible role like this. "source /etc/synopsys/bin/env.sh".

Answer (score 2):

- First, each Ansible tasks running inside a separate sub-process.
- Second, sub-processes can't have effects on their parent processes.

So, for the task which runs `source env.sh` command, it really does nothing to the Ansible process and the following tasks.

For your question, you can run the `source env.sh` command first before running ansible command.

Or using ansible `--extra-vars` or `-e` option to avoid hard-coding values in your playbook.

```
source /etc/synopsys/bin/env.sh
ansible-playbook your-playbook.yml

# OR
ansible-playbook -e SITEID=xxx -e MYGLOBAL=yyy your-playbook.yml
```

Comment: You may want to address the `env` output. `env` is only going to show variables marked for export. Assuming `ansible-playbook` was run from the same shell (this may be the crux of the matter), those variables should be set in the context of the ansible run.